# Is there any way to list down the users in default groups in openshift?

Tags: openshift, usergroups

I want to list down the users in default groups such as system:authenticated, system:authenticated:oauth, system:unauthenticated in openshift.

I got [this link](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html#leveraging-default-groups)
to find out default groups and roles but helpless to list down user in these groups. So i am wondering is there any way to list down in openshift cluster??

`" oc get group "` will not list down the default groups and users.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the current role bindings as follows.
Refer [Viewing cluster role bindings](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_rbac.html#viewing-cluster-bindings)
 for more details.

```
$ oc describe clusterrolebinding.rbac
```

It shows you the role binding with specific groups and users.
For instance, `basic-users` is allowed to `system:authenticated` groups.

```
Name:       basic-users
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate=true
Role:
  Kind: ClusterRole
  Name: basic-user
Subjects:
  Kind  Name            Namespace
  ----  ----            ---------
  Group system:authenticated
```

But some roles grant to users as local role bindings, then you also need to user `$ oc describe rolebinding.rbac`.

```
Name:       admin
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    <none>
Role:
  Kind: ClusterRole
  Name: admin
Subjects:
  Kind  Name    Namespace
  ----  ----    ---------
  User  joe
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But specifically i am looking for a way to list down the user list from default groups(system:authenticated).Like  this # oc get groups
NAME      USERS
west      john, betty

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a way to list it using cli. But you can verify the full list from here: [source code of bootstrappolicy](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-3.11/pkg/cmd/server/bootstrappolicy/constants.go#L34-L44)

Comment: @Deain i tried to list down roles and permissions for a specific user from clusterrolebinding. But it was null. So my assumption is that they might be part of default group such as  system:authenticated,system:authenticated:oauth and system:unauthenticated. So i want to check in which group they belongs to. So is there any other way to find out the roles and permissions for a specific user??? Following is the command i used to get the roles "oc describe clusterrolebinding | grep -B2 $username | awk {'print $1 $2'} | grep Role | sed 's/Role://g' "

Comment: @sandhya You can not verify members of `system:*` using CLI. `Default groups` means applying implicitly all user. For instance, `system:authenticated` is for all authenticated users, `system:unauthenticated` is for all unauthenticated users.